# ¿como mantener en $_SESSION dos filas de registros?

Tags: php, mysql

estoy buscando la manera de mantener en $_SESSION dos o mas filas de registros que son arrojadas por una consulta de mysql, para luego usar esos resultados en otras consultas.
normalmente sacaba una sola fila de registro con:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($consultar))
            {
            $_SESSION["cedula"]=$row["cedula"];
            $_SESSION["nombre"]=$row["nombre"];
            $_SESSION["apellido"]=$row["apellido"];
            }
```

pero eso solo seria mantener en session una sola fila
ahora necesito que me mantenga varias filas en session de esta consulta:

```
$consultar=mysql_query("SELECT * from asignacion where cedula='$_SESSION[cedula]'");
$num=mysql_num_rows($consultar);
if($num==0)
    {
  echo "<script>alert('¡NO HAY EQUIPOS ASIGNADOS A ESTE EMPLEADO!')</script>";
  echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=../vista/devolucion.php'>";
}else{
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($consultar))
          {

    $_SESSION["id_case"]=$row["id_case"];
    $_SESSION["periferico1"]=$row["periferico1"];
    $_SESSION["periferico2"]=$row["periferico2"];
    $_SESSION["periferico3"]=$row["periferico3"];
    $_SESSION["id_laptop"]=$row["id_laptop"];
    }

echo "<script>alert('¡ENCONTRADO!')</script>";
}
```

y poder usarlo para generar una tabla dinamica con esos registros encontrados

```
<?php

    $sqlQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * from equipo where id_case='$_SESSION[id_case]'");
    $table = $sqlQuery or die(mysql_error());
    if ($table) {
        ?>
```

pero todo es dinamico, no se sabe cuantos registros hara el usuario, espero me puedan ayudar y gracias de ante mano

Comment: No uses `mysql` y usa `mysqli` en entornos de producción ya que el primero se ha demostrado que tiene graves problemas de seguridad.

Answer (score 1):

Se entiende que sólo puedes grabar en sesión los datos de un sólo usuario por lo que tu primera consulta funciona pero lo puedes mejorar, puedes investigar [mysql_fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)

En la segunda parte estás sobrescribiendo los resultados, por lo que deberías grabarlo como arreglo, cambia a:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($consultar, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $_SESSION['asignaciones'][] = $row;
}
```

Para recuperarlo en las tablas dinámicas usas:

```
<?php
    foreach($_SESSION['asignaciones'] as $asignacion) {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM equipo WHERE id_case='".$asignacion['id_case']."'");
       .. genera tabla equipos por id_case ..
    }
?>
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes almacenar un array multidimensional sobre un elemento de la sesión:

```
$_SESSION["asignaciones"] = array();

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($consultar)) {
    $asignacion = array();
    $asignacion["id_case"] = $row["id_case"];
    $asignacion["periferico1"] = $row["periferico1"];
    $asignacion["periferico2"] = $row["periferico2"];
    $asignacion["periferico3"] = $row["periferico3"];
    $asignacion["id_laptop"] = $row["id_laptop"];
    $_SESSION["asignaciones"][] = $asignacion;
}
```